# Undefined variable: add_sub_catg_details while using @foreach

Tags: mysql, laravel, foreach

Here is my controller -

```
public function add_sub_main_category($sub_id)
{
                $add_sub_catg_details = Category::add_sub_catg_details($sub_id);
                return View::make('manage')->with('add_sub_catg_details', $add_sub_catg_details);
}
```

Here is my model -

```
public static function add_sub_catg_details($catg_id)
{
    return DB::table('nm_secmaincategory')->where('smc_id', '=', $catg_id)->get();
}
```

Here is my view -

```
@foreach($add_sub_catg_details as $add_sub_catg_det)
<tr>{{$add_sub_catg_det->smc_name}}</tr>
@endforeach
```

My Route -

```
 Route::get('/add_sub_main_category',array('as'=>'add_sub_main_category','uses'=>'CategoryController@add_sub_main_category'));
```

My Schema:

[Category Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9WHbi.png)
[SubCategory Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z0Lde.png)

The Problem I am facing is I  need to get data from the subcategory table based on the smc_mc_id which is the ID column in the Category table and display the name of the item in Sub Category based on the ID's.

Comment: Join both table

Comment: @Komal I don't want to join them. I have may other tables this way. Hence, my question.

Comment: You should define an eloquent relationship between the two tables. Here is a link to the [Laravel Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships) for it.

Comment: @PhillisPeters I'm using Laravel 4.2 and there seems to be no documentation there when I check in the 4.2 section.

Comment: Check it out [here](https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#relationships)... Try implementing it and if you still have a question ask.